# Datatables selected rows are deselected if calling props function

Tags: reactjs, datatables

I have a datatable with the following constructor:

```
var table = $('.select-samples-list').DataTable({
            paging: false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Select all',
                    action: function () {
                        this.popUpperOnChange(table, true);
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Select none',
                    action: function () {
                        this.popUpperOnChange(table, false);
                    }
                }
            ],
            searching: false,
            destroy: true,
            info: false,
            order: [],
            select: {
                style: 'os',
                className: 'selected-experiment-row'
            },
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": 0,
                "data": "download_link",
                "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                    if (row[0] == '') {
                        return '';
                    } else {
                        return '<a target="_blank" href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=' + row[0] + '">' + row[0] + '</a>';
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "targets": 1,
                "data": "download_link",
                "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                    if (row[0] == '') {
                        return '<a target="_blank" href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=' + row[1] + '">' + row[1] + '</a>';
                    } else {
                        return '';
                    }
                } 
            }
            ],
            aoColumns: [
                {sTitle: ' ', sWidth: "100%"},
                {sTitle: 'Name', sWidth: "100%"},
                {sTitle: 'Age', sWidth: "100%"},
                {sTitle: 'Gender', sWidth: "100%"},
                {sTitle: 'Disease', sWidth: "100%"},
                {sTitle: 'Tissue', sWidth: "100%"},
                {sTitle: 'Norm', sWidth: "100%"},
            ],
            data: dataForTable,
        });
```

The popUpper function is the next:

```
       popUpperOnChange (table, state) {
    var selected = [];
    table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
        var data = this.data();
        if (data[0] == '') {
            selected.push(data[1]);
        }
    });
    this.props.onAllChange(selected, state, table);
}
```

And finally my onAllChange function is:

```
       onSelectAll (samples, state, table) {
    let selected = this.state.selected;
    if (state) {
        for(let i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
            selected.add(samples[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for(let i = 0; i < samples.length; i++){
            selected.delete(samples[i]);
        }
    }
    this.setState({
        selected: selected
    });
}
```

My question is when I click select all / select none buttons above my datatables, rows are not selected, but selected field in the state of the parent component is updated and I can see the result in console.log.

From my point of view there must be some "this" conflict going on, but I have no idea how could I overcome this. I tried rebinding this to self/that/etc, but I didnt have any effect at all.

Any help is appreciated.